# Pulsar GoClient Equivalent of unacked_messages_timeout_ms (py-client)

Tags: python, go, apache-pulsar, python-pulsar

In Pulsar Python Client, there is subscriber option `unacked_messages_timeout_ms` to set the interval after which the unacked messages will be redelivered.

What is the equivalent of that in Pulsar Go Client ?

Python

```
py_consumer = client.subscribe(
    topic='my-topic',
    subscription_name="py-subscriber",
    unacked_messages_timeout_ms=10000,
    consumer_type=pulsar.ConsumerType.Shared
    )
```

Golang

```
go_consumer, err := client.Subscribe(
    pulsar.ConsumerOptions{
    Topic: "my-topic",
    SubscriptionName: "go-subscriber",
    Type: pulsar.Shared,
    unacked_messages_timeout_ms ????
})
```

I could not find anything here: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/apache/pulsar-client-go/pulsar#ConsumerOptions

if it s not there, how to configure the re-delivery interval and what is the default value ?

Same question asked in Github Issues too: https://github.com/apache/pulsar-client-go/issues/608

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "unacked messages timeout" is kind of a deprecated feature that was introduced long time ago.

More recently we have added the concept of "negative acks" to provide the application an easy way to handle failure in the processing of a message.

Since the Go client was written when negative acks were already available, we decided to not introduce the deprecated feature in there.

Comment: more information can be checked [here](https://github.com/apache/pulsar/pull/3703) and [here](https://github.com/apache/pulsar/pull/4103).

Comment: What if consumer crashed after consuming message but before ack/nack the message? In that case does broker redeliver message? @matteo-meril?

Comment: @sagarr Yes, when a consumer crashes, all the unacked messages are always automatically marked up for redelivery.